# Serializer List of objects grouping them by foreign key attribute

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Similar to the issue found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483877/django-rest-framework-groupby-modelserializer) (and [maybe here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123148/writable-nested-serializer-with-existing-objects-using-django-rest-framework-3-2))

I had the problem of having a model like so:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=64)
```

and wanting to serialize a list grouped by category like so:

```
[{'name': 'category 1', 'items: [ {'name': 'item1}, {'name':'item2'} ]},
 {'name': 'category 2', 'items: [ {'name': 'item3}, {'name':'item4'} ]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found looks like this:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['name']

class ItemsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name', 'items']

    def get_items(self, obj):
        items = Items.objects.filter(category=obj)  # Or do some other filtering here
        return ItemSerializer(instance=items, many=True).data
```

Very basic. I couldn't find this solution anywhere else though

Comment: Does this work?  Shouldn't this be part of your question? And shouldn't the question be about why this isn't behaving like you want?